# Debian virtual machine backup

Tags: linux, debian, backup, azure

I have a Debian virtual machine on Microsoft Azure, and I want to move it to another server. Can I take a backup of the Debian virtual machine through the terminal?

I am hosting a website on Apache2 on the virtual machine, and I want to ensure that I don't lose any data. How can I do this?

1. Can I back it up to a place like GitHub?
2. Can I load the backup onto my desktop computer?

Yes, there is PostgreSQL on Docker. I want everything included, all the config files. If I take a snapshot or recovery through Microsoft Azure, the data stays on Azure, but I want to store it externally. I want to have it in a place with easy access, like on GitHub, where I can access it anytime. I want to take the backup and continue from where I left off on any server I want.

Answer (score 4):

Azure VM disks (and their backups/snapshots) are just VHD files that you can download and store anywhere with enough space: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/download-vhd.

Note: you should shut down the VM before downloading the disk files

---

If you want to run that VM on your local machine in Hyper-V for example, you'll need to follow some steps to convert it, like:

1. Download the disk from Azure
2. Convert the disk from VHD to VHDX using PowerShell `Convert-VHD -Path [your path.vhd] -DestinationPath [your destination path.vhdx]`
3. Create a VM in Hyper-V and attach this new VHDX
4. [optional] Turn off enhanced session mode on Hyper-V Manager [due to remote desktop services being [disabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/learn-more/use-local-resources-on-hyper-v-virtual-machine-with-vmconnect) on this VM]

There are more [conversion steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/virtual-machines/vhd-not-supported-vm-azure) if you want to put that VM back into Azure.